# Ansible convert curl request with --data-urlencode

Tags: curl, ansible, gitlab, uri, urlencode

I want to upload an HTML file to GitLab through its REST API with Ansible.

My curl request is working fine:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --request POST  --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: my_tocken' --data-urlencode content@/tmp/report.html 'https://my_server/api/v4/projects/3/repository/files/my_customer%2Freportname%2Ehtml?branch=master&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20report' -k
```

How to translate it with the uri module?

```
uri:
  url: "https://my_server/api/v4/projects/3/repository/files/my_customer%2Freportname%2Ehtml?branch=master&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20report"
  validate_certs: no
  method: POST
  headers:
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     PRIVATE-TOKEN: "my_tocken"
  status_code: 200
  body: "data-urlencode=content@/tmp/report.html"
```

I get:

```
 "json": {
    "error": "content is missing"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/tmp/report.html` is on the Ansible controller machine, then:

```
uri:
  url: "https://my_server/api/v4/projects/3/repository/files/my_customer%2Freportname%2Ehtml?branch=master&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20report"
  validate_certs: no
  method: POST
  headers:
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     PRIVATE-TOKEN: "my_tocken"
  status_code: 200
  body: content={{ lookup('file', '/tmp/report.html') | urlencode }}
```

If it's on a different target, you need to [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/slurp_module.html) the data first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Techraf, you are right.

The correct request is:

```
 - name:  Gitlab | upload file
       uri:
         url: "https://my_server/api/v4/projects/3/repository/files/my_customer%2Freportname%2Ehtml?branch=master&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20report%20for%20server"
        validate_certs: no
         method: POST
         headers:
            Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            PRIVATE-TOKEN: "my_tocken"
      status_code: 201
      body: "content={{ lookup('file', '/tmp/report.html')|urlencode }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: There's no need to post a separate answer, I can edit mine. Better, please, fix your question, because you wrote `--data-urlencode content@/tmp/report.html` was working ok.